# set_include_path vs ini_set?

Tags: php, include-path, php-ini

In PHP, what's the difference between [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) and [`ini_set('include_path')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)?

For example:

```
set_include_path('my_path');

ini_set('include_path', 'my_path');
```

For some reason I've always used `ini_set`, but what may be the advantages / disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: I can only notice that `set_include_path` available since PHP 4.3

Comment: @Akam, are there some *settings* that may cause one to work and the other not to?

Comment: I think they are same :) I cant conclude any difference.